# eval() function in object-oriented programming

Tags: python, oop, eval

Here's the thing: My program is a GUI-based calculator written in python/GTK. In the first version I didn't used classes, so here is a piece of the old code:

```
def show(result):
     textbox3.set_text( str(result) )
     (...) # Update counters, etc.

def on_button_pressed(*args):
    input_user = inputbox.get_text() 
    (...) # parsing of the input
    show( eval( input_user ) )
```

For instance, if I type on inputbox "12+3" and press the button, textbox3 show the result "15".

I've modified my project to use OOP. Here's the modified code:

```
class App:
    (...)

    def show(self,result):
         self.textbox3.set_text( str(result) )
         (...) # Update counters, etc.

    def on_button_pressed(self,*args):
        input_user = self.inputbox.get_text() 
        (...) # parsing of the input
        print input_user
        self.show( eval( input_user ) )
```

With this code, the textbox3 show the result `"<app.c12app.App instance at 0x272e128>"`. Which mistake am I making here?

P.S.:
The real code is too large, the parsing section is about 50 lines large. I added a line `print input_user` to proof that the parsing don't overwrite the variable `input_user`. The console prints the expression parsed (a string) correctly. But when I use the `eval` function in this string it returns an object, instead the numeric value of the expression.

Comment: What is `input_user`? Paste the rest of your `on_button_pressed` method. I have a feeling you may be overwriting `input_user` somewhere.

Comment: you are not calling the *method* `self.show()` here. You are still calling a function `show()`; no idea what might invoke `App().show()`, but it is not in the code you show here.

Comment: The output you show look like you were instead passing in `self` explicitly somewhere: `self.show(self)`.

Comment: In other words: the code you added in the question wouldn't work, and if it did, would not show the result you shared with us. Please share your real code.

Comment: The real code is too large, the parsing section is about 50 lines large. I modified the `self.show` (it was wrong, indeed) and added a line `print input_user` to proof that the parsing don't overwrite the variable input_user. The console prints the expression parsed (a string) correctly. But when I use the `eval` function in this string it returns an object, instead the numeric value of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a couple things.  First off, don't do `class App():` in your definition, do `class App:`, and make sure you instantiate like `foo = App()` and not `foo = App`.

Comment: Ok.  This string `<app.c12app.App instance at 0x272e128>` represents an instance of one of your App objects (in memory), and the code/behavior can't really lie.  Somehow you are not evaluating something as simple as `12+3`.  Since you're parsing for 50 lines anyway, you may as well find a way to get rid of `eval()`.  It makes your program easily breakable, or worse...

Comment: I've found my error. I should define the show function as `def show(self, dummy, result):` Independently if I pass just one argument to the function (like in `self.show(result)`, it seems python passes two "invisible arguments": the first is "self", the instance of the class and the second is the method who called the function (the function `on_button_pressed` or the button objetct, i'm not sure). That's a bit confusing...

Answer (score 0):

I've found my error. I should define the show function as

```
def show(self, dummy, result):
```

Independently if I pass just one argument to the function (like in `self.show(result)`, it seems python passes two "invisible arguments": the first is "self", the instance of the class and the second is the method who called the function (the function on_button_pressed or the button objetct, i'm not sure). That's a bit confusing...

the first and the second arguments are useless for me, but apparently I'm forced to declare them.